# Open Layers 3 layer visibility - problems passing variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, openlayers-3

I have got together a pretty basic function which turns on a layer I have on my map.

This is the code for initialising the layer:

```
var featurelayer;

featurelayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
      name: 'featurelayer',
      source: new ol.source.TileWMS({url: 'http://myserver/geoserver/wms',
      serverType: 'geoserver',
      params:{
        'LAYERS':"layergroup:mylayer", 'TILED':true
      }
      }),
      visible: false
      });
map.addLayer(featurelayer);
```

I have a list item on my site which when clicked activates a function that I am using to try to turn the layer on. My html and jQuery function is below:

```
<li class='last'><a href='#'><i class="fa fa-circle text-info"></i><span> Flood Zone 3b (Functional Floodplain)</span></a></li>

$("a.layer").click(function() {
  map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer) {
    if (layer.get('name') === this.id) {
      featurelayer.setVisible(true);
    }
  });
});
```

This code actually works, it displays the layer on the map. My problem is I will have more than one layer, and ideally I want to be able to pass the ID from my list item which is the same name as the layer to my setVisible event.

I cannot seem to work out how to do this as my console log is always returning undefined; I have tried creating a variable which I am equaling to 'this.id' but that doesn't work - do I need to pass my ID through my click function? Why am I receiving an undefined error if it is registering that my layer name matches my list item ID?

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't *this.id* trying to access 'layer.id' (which may be undefined) as it's inside the *forEach* loop?

Try getting the id before entering the loop:

```
 $("a.layer").click(function () {
        var lid = $(this).attr('id');
        map.getLayers().forEach(function (layer) {
            if (layer.get('name') == lid) {
                layer.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    });
```

EDIT: Is this what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/fbma/3z1L6ttn/1/

I've added ids to both li items, and the click event is related to class 'last'. Also, visibility is set on the layer object of the iteration.

Comment: Thank you for replying, unfortunately that didn't work :(

Comment: @Chris note that **in your case** the click is bound to the `<a>` and in @Fbma fiddle the click is bound to the `<li>`. So put if you want the click on `<a>` put the `class` and `id` on it, like: `<a href='#' class='last' id='layer1'>`

Comment: Thank you Fbma for updating your response - I have tried this out and it works to an extent!
The issue is that it only makes the layer you click on visible and hides the others; what I really would like to do is to be able to toggle the layers. I think this approach works well for base maps where you only want one displaying, but will need some tweaking so it doesn't interfere with the status of other layers.

Comment: I have just tried to add a bit more so that it looks to see if the layer is already visible, but it doesn't return the layer. I am using the getVisible() method from the OL3 API but I am not sure if I need to create a variable first and then use it in the if statement?...


`if (layer.get('name') == lid) {
              if (layer.getVisible() == 'false') {
                layer.setVisible(true);
              }
              if (layer.getVisible() == 'true') {
                layer.setVisible(false);
              }
            }`

Answer (score 0):

I took Fbma's answer and added a couple more if statements to check if the layer is already visible through setting a variable calling the getVisible() method, so the below code is now working, thank you for your help!

```
$(".layerlist").click(function() {
        var lid = $(this).attr('id');
        map.getLayers().forEach(function (layer) {
            if (layer.get('name') == lid) {
              var visibility = layer.getVisible();
              if (visibility == false) {
                layer.setVisible(true);
              }
              if (visibility == true) {
                layer.setVisible(false);
              }
            }

        });
    });
```